# How to see the all queries ran from Kibana Dev tool

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

If want to see, all the ran queries, from Kibana Dev tool, how to see it? Is there any query, which shows all the ran queries may be for last 30 days?

Answer (score 2):

I guess there is no Api for showing history of executed queries how ever you can find the related log files in  var/log/elasticsearch file path More over if you want to always keep record of all executed queries and events in your Dev tools you can create and index for it and use Logstash to insert your operation logs(which previously said where is stored) into that index.